# MPI_Reduce MINLOC double index?

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, mpi

So I have an array of intengers to each processor and I want to find the minimum element to each one and save the index of row and column.

After I find the minimum element to each individual processor I need to call MPI_reduce to find the minimum and send the I,j index.

I saw that MINLOC can help if there is only one index in the struct like the following:

```
struct {
     int min;
     int index_i;
} in, out;
```

But what if I want to send both row and column index?
an array in struct does not solve the problem.

Is there another way to achieve this?
I am writing in C.

Thanks for your time :D.

Comment: If you _know_ the array dimensions (e.g. `int array[YMAX * XMAX]`), the linear/absolute index can be converted back to row/column: `yidx = absidx / XMAX; xidx = absidx % XMAX;` This even works with `int array[YMAX][XMAX];`. If the individual indexes are: `xidx` and `yidx`, then compute: `absidx = (yidx * YMAX) + xidx;` Send this back. Then, recover the row/column from the first method

Comment: Correction: The last equation should be: `absidx = (yidx * XMAX) + xidx;`

Comment: This is what I needed dude, thank you!!! In array you have YMAX and then XMAX, so the absidx was correct in the first comment :D